# Анимация в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, исключения

В коде C# имеется обработчик события **MouseEnter**:

```
private void ellipse_MouseEnter(Ellipse ellipse, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation opacity = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            To = 0.9,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4)),
        };

        ColorAnimation color = new ColorAnimation()
        {
            To = Colors.White,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4)),
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(opacity, ellipse);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacity, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));

        DependencyProperty[] propertyChain = new DependencyProperty[] { Ellipse.FillProperty, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(color, transformBrush);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", propertyChain));

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(opacity);
        sb.Children.Add(color);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Делал по примеру на **MSDN**
Но из-за строк:

```
DependencyProperty[] propertyChain = new DependencyProperty[] { Ellipse.FillProperty, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(color, transformBrush);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(color, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", propertyChain));
```

вылазит **Exception**:
'Fill' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.

Помогите пожалуйста, или помогите сделать анимацию свойства **Fill** для элемента **ellipse**
Спасибо

Comment: А почему вы делаете анимацию не в XAML? Так было бы проще.

Comment: Согласен на все 100%, но дело в том что у меня есть кнопочка по нажатию на которую генерируется элипс, которому присваивается это событие, поэтому к сожалению Ваш вариант тут не пройдет, наверное...
Но если можно как-то это сделать (хотя я сомневаюсь) то напишите пожалуйста :) буду премного благодарен

Comment: @MikroFF

- Правильно, как мне кажется, было вынести настройки анимации и стиля выбранного эллипса в `XAML,` а из вашего кода (по нажатию на соответствующую кнопку) просто добавлять эллипс с такими то настройками анимации в `LayoutRoot.`

- При этом проставлять правильные свойства (т.е референс на уже имеющиеся настройки анимации) объекту `Ellipse` можно руками в коде, а можно и пользоваться чем-нибудь типа `(Ellipse) XamlReader.Load(@"<...>")`.

- Это ведь можно сделать, не так ли? `:)`

Comment: Ну если Вы говорите значит можно :)
Но я, как Вы уже поняли, в WPF и XAML ничего не шарю, почти, так как пришел из WinForms. Если бы Вы могли мне скинуть ссылку на Ваш пример то я был бы примного благодарен :)

Comment: Я уже даже разобрался как сделать эту анимацию цвета, но мне все равно интересно как ее сделать через XAML

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам простейшая наработка, показывающая некоторые элементы программирования на MVVM. только не забудьте создать простенький `public class ellipseVm` (и если хотите, добавить туда пару свойств).

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestProject1" 
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:ellipseVm}">
            <Ellipse x:Name="elTemplate">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>
                <Ellipse.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="elTemplate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.9" Duration="0:0:.4" />
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="elTemplate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)" To="White" Duration="0:0:.4" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="elTemplate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:.4" />
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="elTemplate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).(Color)" Duration="0:0:.4" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Ellipse.Triggers>
            </Ellipse>

        </DataTemplate>
        <my:ellipseVm MyProperty="1" MyProperty2="2" x:Key="CUSTOMELLIPSE" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource CUSTOMELLIPSE}" Width="100" Height="100" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```